# SQL: exclude duplicates

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I need to remove duplicates in a SELECT statement.

The Tabel looks like this:

```
| name 1 | name 2|
| John   | Lukas |
| Simon  | John  |
| Lukas  | John  |
| Lukas  | Simon |
```

The output should be as following:

```
name 1   name 2
John     Lukas
Simon    John
(Lukas    John) this should be excluded
Lukas    Simon
```

But there is again once Lukas John in it. I tryed with Distinct, but It doesent work. Can anybody please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: While what you want is possible but this looks like a serious design problem. Why don't you specify the columns as first name and last name. Also by deleting duplicates are you considering that no two people can have same names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is:

```
select name1, name2
from t
where name1 < name2 or
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name1 = t.name2 and t2.name2 = t.name1);
```

This assumes that the duplicates are only pairs that might be in the opposite order.  If you can have complete duplicates, then use `select distinct`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for!